# OpenZeppelin test helper: expectEvent.inTransaction error

Tags: javascript, events, testing, openzeppelin, ethers.js

I'm trying to use [OZ Test helpers](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/test-helpers/0.5/api) to pass a test when a specific event is emitted. Here is the logic:

- I call function1 with a JS Promise.
- function1 calls function2 which emits an event.

Parts of code have been omitted for readability:

test.js

```
const { expectEvent } = require('@openzeppelin/test-helpers');
const { ethers }      = require("hardhat");

describe("test", function() => {
let mycontract;

before( async() => {
    const Mycontract = await ethers.getContractFactory("MyContract");
    mycontract = await Mycontract.deploy();
})

it("expected event is emitted.", async() => {

    const{ hash } = await mycontract.function1();

    await expectEvent.inTransaction(hash, mycontract, "THIS_EVENT",
     {message:"This event has happened."} );
 });
});
```

myContract.sol

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

contract MyContract
{
string message;

constructor(){
 _message = "This event has happened."
}

event THIS_EVENT(string message);

function1() {
 function2();
}

function2() {
 emit THIS_EVENT("_message")
 }

}
```

Error message:

```
     Error: Unknown contract object
```

How can I write a test to pass when a specific event is emitted as a result of a nested function call ?

Your time is much appreciated,
**Edit**
hardhat: 2.2.1
test-helpers: 0.1.4

Comment: Okay can u please add the versions of the libraries

Comment: @MajdTL just added

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
it('expected event is emitted', async function() {
    const receipt = await this.mycontract.function1();
    expectEvent(receipt, 'THIS_EVENT', {
        message: 'This event has happened.',
    });
});
```

Comment: Your code returns: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRep' of undefined
`However when I replace `this.mycontract` with `mycontract` I get : `     Error: Unknown transaction receipt object
`

Comment: Okay sorry I tested that on truffle and not hardhat